# How to prove this problem about functions of a complex variable?

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

Let $\phi_{n}$ : ${\bf C}$\{0} $\rightarrow$ ${\bf C}$ be the analytic function
$$ 
\phi_n(z) = 1+ \frac{1}{z}+ \frac{1}{2!z^2}+ \cdots +\frac{1}{n!z^n}.
$$
Let $M>0$ be given. How to show that for sufficiently large n, all the zeros of $\phi_n(z)$ lie in the disc {$z: |z|<M$}.

Comment: Looks like partial sum of $e^(1/z)$ series.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_n(w)=\phi_n(1/w)=1+ \frac{w}{1}+ \frac{w^2}{2!}+ \cdots +\frac{w^n}{n!}$ for all $w$ complex; now a root $z_0$ of $\phi_n$ corresponds to a root $w_0=1/z_0$ of $f_n$ and clearly $f_n(0)=1$ so we do not worry about that.

But now $f_n(w)$ converges uniformly on compact sets to $e^w$ which has no zeroes, so in particular given a compact set $K$, there is $n(K)$ st all the zeroes of $f_n$ are outside $K$ for $n \ge n(K)$ (as otherwise an accumulation point for them in $K$ would give a zero of $e^w$).

Applying this with $K$ the compact set $|w| \le 1/M$ gives the required result!